# rbenv init - が正常に動かない

Tags: ruby, rbenv

こんにちは。よろしくお願いします。

`rbenv`をgitからクローンし、ドキュメントに書いてあるようにパスを設定して`eval "$(rbenv init -)"`これを`.bashrc`に追加したんですが、シェルを再起動すると以下のようなメッセージが出てしまいます。どう対応すればよいでしょうか。

この問題は調べても情報が一切見つからなかったので、Stackoverflowに質問させていただきました。

OS: `Linux alice1017 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

````
bash: export: `'/home/username/.rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `2>/dev/null': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `rbenv()': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `{': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `[': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `"$#"': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `-gt': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `0': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `];': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `"$command"': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `rehash|shell)': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `"`rbenv': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `"sh-$command"': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `"$@"`";;': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `*)': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `"$command"': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `"$@";;': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `}': not a valid identifier```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ rbenv init -
```

の実行結果はどうなるでしょうか?

手元の環境(Mac OS X)では、

```
export PATH="/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source '/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'
rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "`rbenv "sh-$command" "$@"`";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
```

となりました。出ているエラーメッセージに近いフレーズが見受けられます。
( 手元の環境では、`eval "$(rbenv init -)"` はエラーとなっていません。 )
これの実行結果がおかしいためevalするとエラーメッセージとなるのか、evalコマンド実行前後で何か別の文字が紛れてしまっているのではないかと予想します。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。自分の環境では、`rbenv init -` は回答者様と同様の結果が出力されます。
bashrcには、このように記述しています
`export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH`この下に
`eval '$(rbenv init -)'`

Comment: `eval '$(rbenv int -)'`を`eval "$(rbenv int -)"`に変更する( シングルクォートをダブるクォートに変更する )と上手くいくと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。MIURA様の指摘どおり、シングルクオートをダブルクオートにしたら無事に起動しました。シングルクオートとダブルクオートでなぜこのようなバグが生まれるのでしょうか… 今後に活かしたいと思います。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決してよかったです。シングルクォートとダブルクォートでは意味が違うのでバグとは呼ばない方がよいと思います。シングルクォートは`$(rbenv init -)`自体を`eval`する事になり、ダブルクォートでは`$(rbenv init -)`の実行結果を`eval`する事になります。この文章だけでは良く分からないと思うので、よかったら「bash シングルクォート ダブルクォート 違い」などで検索してみてください。